# QGIS - Projections all showing up wrong

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Dont kill me on CRS!

Every time I add lat longs using the same CRS as the project they are now starting to mess up and show up in Africa or Asia.... I cant seem to match up the true lat long anymore?
[image: projection screenshot]
This never happened before I always check the project and layer projections (use a default EPSG: 3832)....

I'm sure this is a bug not a user issue?
Anyone have anything similar happen?

Comment: Can you give a bit more of context, and example of the spreadsheet? Specially an example that worked before and one of now that it does not work.

Comment: Could you give at least one sample coordinate? The first record perhaps?

Comment: Its a load of UK postcodes that have been geocoded to Lat Longs. The basemap is open street map and I use a boundary map which aligns perfectly. Over the last few weeks every time I try and add points they are not outputting where they should be.

Comment: Where do you think the data should be? What version of QGIS?

Comment: [EPSG:3832](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3832) is not a lat/long projection units are metres (Eastings/Northings)

Comment: @nmtoken what CRS should I use as default then (using OSM as a basemap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (as it appears) your coordinates are in decimal degrees (i.e. a point in the UK is near 51N 1W) then you need to set the CRS of the **layer** to be EPSG:4326. QGis will then take care of the complicated maths required to make the points show up in the right place regardless of the projection you choose for your map.

**DON'T LIE TO QGIS ABOUT YOUR PROJECTION**, it will become confused and sulk.

Comment: P.S. In all the questions I have seen about CRS and QGIS on this site not one has been a bug rather than user error. Trust the computer it is your friend.

Comment: Oh she is making my life hell at the mo...

Comment: Cool its just that recently I'm getting a lot of (not responding) windows crap when using QGIS... should I update to 3.10 or 3.12?

Comment: I'm using a mix of 3.10 and 3.12 across my machines with no issues